# Javascript: Store rest of array starting from first condition met

Tags: javascript

I have an array object of dates and would like some effective feedback on how to achieve the following:

Say we have an array of houses as follows:

```
{
  "houses": [
    { "available": false, "price": "80000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "700000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "8120000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "120000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "340000" }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter through and get all results starting from first object with available === true - BUT without omitting the rest of objects even if their available property equals to false. The stored or returned result after filtering should be like this:

```
{
  "houses": [
    { "available": true, "price": "8120000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "120000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "340000" }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
const firstAvailableHouseIndex = houses.findIndex(house => house.available === true);

const housesStartingFromFirstAvailable = houses.filter((house, index) => index >= firstAvailableHouseIndex);
```

Comment: "*I would like some effective feedback*" - have you written any code yet?

Comment: Have you tried [array,sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @mikemacccana sort() only sorts values? I am trying to store rest of array once the first condition is met ignoring the rest of properties

Comment: @Bergi yes tried getting the first index of available === false and then filtering houses from that index onwards. It works but it seems verbose.

Comment: @Zeusox Still, please [edit] the question to include that verbose code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const houses = [
    { "available": false, "price": "80000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "700000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "8120000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "120000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "340000" }
];
const firstAvailable = houses.findIndex(house => house.available);
const remaining = houses.slice(firstAvailable < 0 ? houses.length : firstAvailable);
console.log(remaining);
```

Using `houses.slice(houses.length)` in case of none being available might seems a bit verbose, you can also do

```
const remaining = firstAvailable < 0 ? [] : houses.slice(firstAvailable);
```

instead

Comment: You can simplify the slice index using `Math.max` to limit the value to 0 when it's -1 (not found). That works because `slice(0)` is equal to `slice(length)`, it returns the whole array

Therefore the remaining will it be:
`const remaining = houses.slice(Math.max(firstAvailable, 0))`

Comment: @rodrigomd No, `slice(0)` is not the same as `slice(length)` - the latter returns an empty array, which is what is desirable here

Comment: oh, right!  I misread, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```js
const myObject = {
  "houses": [
    { "available": true, "price": "80000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "700000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "8120000" },
    { "available": false, "price": "120000" },
    { "available": true, "price": "340000" }
  ]
};

// Finding the first index of the house which is available
const firstAvailableIndex = myObject.houses?.findIndex(house => house.available === true);
if(firstAvailableIndex !== -1) {
  // Slicing the array from the index to the end
  const result = myObject.houses?.slice(firstAvailableIndex);
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const houses = [
  { "available": false, "price": "80000" },
  { "available": false, "price": "700000" },
  { "available": true, "price": "8120000" },
  { "available": false, "price": "120000" },
  { "available": true, "price": "340000" }
];

const firstAvailableIndex = houses.findIndex(house => house.available === true);

const filteredHouses = houses.filter((house, index) => index >= firstAvailableIndex);

console.log(filteredHouses);
```

use `filter()` to create a new array of houses that only contains elements whose index is greater than or equal to the index of the first available house

Comment: This does not work if no house is available, and using `filter` is unnecessarily inefficient

Comment: Well, he can check for that I assume. Is the question asking for the most efficient way? Then don't use JS in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Array.prototype.findIndex()** and **Array.prototype.slice()** if you want to remove the falses from the start.

Yet, if you want to keep all items, but reordem them, sorting is an option.

```
// find first index and slice from it. If no houses available, return empty array.
const trimUnavailableFromStart = (array) => {
  const firstAvailableIndex = array.findIndex(house => house.available);
  return firstAvailableIndex == -1 ? [] : array.slice(firstAvailableIndex);
}

const startTrimmedHouses = trimUnavailableFromStart(houses);
```

Or you can sort them:

```
// returns new array with all available houses first
const sortByAvailable = (array) => {
  const newArray = [...array].sort(
    (a,b) => (a.available < b.available)
  );
  return newArray;
}

const sortedHouses = sortByAvailable(houses);
```